# Iterating through a list of lists?

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, functional-programming

I have Items from a certain source (populated from somewhere else):

```
public class ItemsFromSource{
    public ItemsFromSource(string name){
        this.SourceName = name;
        Items = new List<IItem>();
    }

    public string SourceName;
    public List<IItem> Items;
}
```

Now in MyClass I have Items from several sources (populated from somewhere else):

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyClass(){
    }

    public List<ItemsFromSource> BunchOfItems;
}
```

Is there a simple way to iterate through all Items in all ItemsFromSources in BunchOfItems in one go?
i.e., something like:

```
foreach(IItem i in BunchOfItems.AllItems()){
    // do something with i
}
```

instead of doing

```
foreach(ItemsFromSource ifs in BunchOffItems){
    foreach(IItem i in ifs){
        //do something with i
    }
}
```

Comment: if ItemsFromSource isA IItem than your first foreach will work, else neither will work.

Comment: I think you should have stated the version of .NET you're using, as some people are offering LINQ as an option, not available with all versions of .NET..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you can use the linq function SelectMany to *flatmap* (create child lists and compress them into one) the values:

```
foreach(var i in BunchOfItems.SelectMany(k => k.Items)) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
foreach(IItem i in BunchOffItems.SelectMany(s => s.Items)){
    // do something with i
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make a function to do that for you.

```
Enumerable<T> magic(List<List<T>> lists) {
  foreach (List<T> list in lists) {
     foreach (T item in list) {
       yield return item;
     }
  }
}
```

Then you just do:

```
List<List<int>> integers = ...;
foreach (int i in magic(integers)) {
  ...
}
```

Also, I think [PowerCollections](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerCollections.aspx) will have something for that out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Used to flatten hierarchical lists
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
    {
        if (items == null) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        return items.Concat(items.SelectMany(i => childSelector(i).Flatten(childSelector)));
    }
```

I think this will work for what you want to do. Cheers.